# How do I vertically align a TextBlock and a TextBox in XAML in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do I align a  to be above a  so that they appeared to be tightly coupled ( on top of ) in XAML? Here is my XAML definition:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical"> 
    <TextBlock Text="NAME" Width="120"/> 
    <TextBox Name="UserNameTextBox" Width="120" /> 
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is to enclose both in a container panel that allows relative positioning, and then just add some vertical padding.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock Text="Heading" />
    <TextBox Margin="0,5,0,0" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: That's what I thought should work. Somehow, but the TextBlock and TextBox are coming up as center aligned. What am I over looking here? Here is my XAML definition:                 <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                    
                    <TextBlock Text="NAME"
                               Width="120"/>
                    <TextBox Name="UserNameTextBox"
                             Width="120" />
                </StackPanel>

Comment: Big Doah! on me. Thanks for your solution.